# Unity 3d my character does not rotate to the raycasthit point I drew

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I draw a rail on my central character with the direction of the front of my camera. I use `Rigidbody.LookRotation` to make the character return to that point, but it doesn't.

```
private void Update()
{
    Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 3, 0), mainCam.transform.forward, out hit);
    Quaternion lookrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(hit.point.x,0,hit.point.z));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookrotation, Time.deltaTime * 2);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 3, 0),hit.point);
    Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
}
```

[image: My Scene]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance there are two points:

1. [`LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) expects a forward **direction** .. currently you only give it a **position**.

   you would rather want to use e.g.

   ```
   if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 3, 0), mainCam.transform.forward, out var hit))
   {
       var direction = hit.point - transform.position;
       direction.y = 0;
       var lookrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. currently you also rotate just real slow. Assuming 60 Fps Each frame you interpolate with a factor of about `1/60 * 2` so about `0.033..` from the current towards the target rotation. So this gets even slower the closer you get to the target rotation.

   You would rather either not multiply by `Time.deltaTime` but use a constant factor e.g. `0.5f`

   or use [`RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) and provide a continous `anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime`.